# Compute $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{1/3}}{(x^2 + 1)^2} dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

So I want to compute $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{1/3}}{(x^2 + 1)^2} dx$ using complex analysis, Cauchys theorem and the residue theorem.

What I did was the following: define $g(z) = e^{1/3(\ln|z| + i\phi)}$, with $\phi \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2})$. We are interested in the complex integral of $ h(z) = \frac{g(z)}{(z^2 + 1)^2}$

Using a contour consisting of four parts, an interval from $[\epsilon, R]$, half a circle with radius R, an interval from $[-R, -\epsilon]$ and half a circle with radius $\epsilon$. With $R > 1$ and $\epsilon < 1$. We construct a closed contour over which we can integrate that only contain one singular value, $i$. I was able to compute all those separate integrals. All those seperate integrals combined form a closed contour so that we can use Cauchy his theorem and the residue theorem, however.

The problem is that I can't compute the residue of $h(z)$ in $z = i$, because of the following: rewriting $(z^2 + 1)^2 = (z-i)^2(z+i)^2$ and using the residue theorem we have to compute the derivative of $g(z)(z+i)^{-2}$ and evaluate it in $i$. But am I allowed to just compute the derivative of $g(z)$? If this is allowed, what will it become? If this is not allowed, how could I solve this problem?

Comment: Make clear the interval to which $\;\phi\;$ belongs. Should it actually be $\;\left[-\frac\pi2,\,\,\frac\pi2\right]\;$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can compute the residue at $z= i$, your cut removes $z = -i$ and the origin.
$$\text{Res}(i) = \lim_{z \to i}\frac{d}{dz}\left ( (z-i)^2\frac{z^{1/3}}{(z-i)^2 (z +i)^2} \right ) = -ie^{i\pi/6}/6$$